# Recreating iOS Camera app overlay buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, camera, uikit

I'm trying to recreate the Camera.app buttons and interface from iOS in my own, custom camera application built on GPUFilter. Specifically talking about the Flash, Options, and front vs back camera button toggle that are across the top of the app:

[image: camera app]

Curious to know if these are built into Storyboards as UI objects or if there's another easy way to recreate these without totally reprogramming. I'm also interested in using the overlay table view that they use (in picture above) for options.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using AVCamCaptureManager and AVCamRecorder classes. Apple has a demo program build on its developer site [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112).

Comment: I glanced at the code here but didn't see specifically where they add these buttons, just the general camera. Did I overlook something?

Comment: if you open the xib file of that AVCam project, you'll find a small UIView object. This view is responsible for displaying the camera's feed. You can resize that view as per the size you want and the camera's input will be displayed in that much area. You can also put the frame image around it as per your choice.

It worked for me when I wanted to resize the camera's input feed and capture photos. I hope it works for you as well.